# How to fix overfull \hbox in multiline equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{1in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.15in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.75in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \nonumber &E_{AH}^* = (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) = \Big(\frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B}, \frac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)},\\ \nonumber &\frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack},
    \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack},\\
     &\frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack}\Big). \label{Eqn: EEAH}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

and the output looks like this.
[image: the second line is overfulled]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The equation is simply longer than the allowable horizontal space, split it over five lines for readability. When splitting lines, you should have the same virtual space as if the `=` sign is present in all lines. To do this, insert `\phantom{{}={}}` at the beginning of lines without `=`. Moreover, the two braces `{}={}` are added because `=` is a binary operator just like `+` or `-` and these braces act as math atoms for correct spacing around the `=` sign.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{1in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.15in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.75in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \nonumber E_{AH}^* &= (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) \\ \nonumber
    &= \Big(\frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B}, \frac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)},\\ \nonumber 
    &\phantom{{}={}} \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}, \\ \nonumber
    &\phantom{{}={}} \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack},\\
    &\phantom{{}={}} \frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack}\Big). \label{Eqn: EEAH}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd be tempted to include a `\Big(` in the `\vphantom` to emphasize that those big fractions are contained within the parens by lining them all up with the first one.

Answer (score 13):

Your readers will have a hard time in finding the correspondence between symbols and their expansion. I'd suggest centering the main equation and explain the symbols below it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
E_{AH}^* = (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) \label{Eqn: EEAH} \\
\begin{align*}
S_b^* &= \frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B} \\
I_b^* &= \frac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)} \\
S_h^* &=
  \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}
       {\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}[\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)]}
  \\
I_a^* &=
  \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}[\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)]}
       {(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\bigl[\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}
        \bigl(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\bigr)\bigr]}
  \\
R_h^* &=
  \frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}[\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)]}
       {\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\bigl[\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+
        \beta_{BH}\bigl(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\bigr)\bigr]}. 
\end{align*}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would (a) introduce one more line break and (b) align all rows vertically (with offsets) relative to the first `=` symbol. I would also increase the space between successive rows a bit and increase the size of the outermost parenthesis from `\Big` to `\bigg`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{1in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.15in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.75in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
E_{AH}^* &= (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) \notag \\[1ex]
&= \biggl(\frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B}, 
   \frac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)}, \notag \\[1.5ex]
&\qquad \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}, \notag \\[1.5ex]
&\qquad \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\bigl(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\bigr)\big\rbrack}, \notag \\[1.5ex]
&\qquad\frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\bigl(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\bigr)\big\rbrack}\biggr). \label{Eqn: EEAH}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Three other variants on 4 lines:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}
     \newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
    E_{AH}^*&=\mathrlap{(S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) } \\
     & = & \biggl(\frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B}, \mfrac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)}, \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack} & , \\
    & & \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack} & , \\
     & & \frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack} &\biggr). \label{Eqn: EEAH}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\bigskip
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
    E_{AH}^*&=\mathrlap{(S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) } \\
     & = \begin{multlined}[t] \biggl(\frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B}, \mfrac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)}, \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack} , \\
    \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack} , \\
    \frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack} \biggr).
     \end{multlined} \label{Eqn: EEAH}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\bigskip
\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2}
    E_{AH}^*&=\mathrlap{(S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) } \\
     & = & \biggl(\frac{\mu_b + \delta_b}{\beta_B},& \frac{\Lambda_b\beta_B - \mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\beta_B(\mu_b + \delta_b)}, \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)}{\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack} , \\
    & & & \frac{\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack} , \\
     & & & \frac{\gamma_a\Lambda_h\beta_{BH}\lbrack\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\rbrack}{\mu_h(\mu_h+d+\gamma_a)\big\lbrack\mu_h\beta_B(\mu_b+\delta_b)+\beta_{BH}\big(\Lambda_b\beta_B-\mu_b(\mu_b+\delta_b)\big)\big\rbrack} \biggr). \label{Eqn: EEAH}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]